# Publish Actions not working on Open Graph App

Tags: action, publish, facebook-opengraph

Really struggling with the postCook() function following the Open Graph tutorial.

The code on the tutorial is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function postCook() {  
    FB.api('/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook' + '?recipe=http://example.com/cookie.html','post',   
    function(response) {  
      if (!response || response.error) {  
        alert('Error occured');  
      } else {  
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);     
      }  
    });  
   }  
</script>
```

I've replaced their actions and objects with my actions and objects yet I still get error messages.

Comment: It would help to detail exactly what error messages you are getting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me.

I just get the alert popping up saying "Error Occured", it doesn't say what error or why. So frustrating.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here to create actions for your application? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/.  Each action your application uses must be [approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/) by Facebook...

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug some more, use firebug or similar tool and console.log the response you get from facebook. That will give you a clear idea of what is wrong.

if (!response || response.error) { 
   console.log(response);
   ...
 }

or alert(response.error) will do.